# Remove empty lists from a tibble in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to remove any list from my tibble that has "<chr [0]>"

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(as.character()), 
             z=list(as.character("ATC"),as.character("TAC"), as.character()))
df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>       x y         z        
#>   <int> <list>    <list>   
#> 1     1 <chr [0]> <chr [1]>
#> 2     2 <chr [0]> <chr [1]>
#> 3     3 <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I want my tibble to look like this

```
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>       x  z        
#>    <int> <list>   
#> 1     1 <chr [1]>
#> 2     2 <chr [1]>
#> 3     3    NA
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: might help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583913/how-to-recode-null-cells-to-nested-na-lgl-1-in-a-tibbles-list-column

Comment: thank you user63230, thats a great thread to have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
  select(where(~!all(lengths(.) == 0))) %>%
  mutate(z = lapply(z, function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0, NA, x)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x z        
  <int> <list>   
1     1 <chr [1]>
2     2 <chr [1]>
3     3 <lgl [1]>
```

Note, in your z column you can‘t have list elemtents for row 1 and 2 and a direct logical value NA. The whole column needs to be a list.

If all elements of z have only one element, you can add another line of code with `mutate(z = unlist(z))`.

---

TO asked for a more dynamic solution to pass several columns.

Here is an example where I simply created another z2 variable. Generally, you can repeat the recoding for several columns using `across`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(as.character()), 
             z=list(as.character("ATC"),as.character("TAC"), as.character()),
z2 = z)

df %>%
  select(where(~!all(lengths(.) == 0))) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('z'), ~ lapply(., function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0, NA, x))))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x z         z2       
  <int> <list>    <list>   
1     1 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
2     2 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
3     3 <lgl [1]> <lgl [1]>
```

Comment: Thank you deschen, for the answer. It looks great

Comment: Hi deschen, one quetsion. If you d have to use the  mutate(z = lapply(z, function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0, NA, x))) for a specific range of columns how would you do it? 
e.g., mutate_at(vars(2:last_col(), lapply....)

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! that was really useful to me! Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

A two-step way using base R:

```r
df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(as.character()), 
             z=list(as.character("ATC"),as.character("TAC"), as.character()))


df <- df[apply(df, 2, function(x) any(lapply(x, length) > 0))] #Remove empty columns
df[apply(df, 2, function(x) lapply(x, length) == 0)] <- NA #Replace empty lists with NA

df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x z        
  <int> <list>   
1     1 <chr [1]>
2     2 <chr [1]>
3     3 <NULL>
```

Comment: Thank you Maël, thats a very neat solution

Comment: Isn’t it redundant to include `== T` in your logical tests?

Comment: You're right! TThey are removed now